# Using qualityOfService instead of threadPriority iOS

Tags: ios8, nsoperation, ios9

As we know, the threadPriority property of NSOperation is deprecated iOS 8 onwards and it is recommended that we use qualityOfService instead. Since threadPriority was a double type it could be assigned any value from 0 to 1. But qualityOfService conforms to certain discrete values. I am using a third party class named PDFThumbCache/(now known as ReaderThumbCache) which sets threadPriority like this:

```
[thumbFetch setThreadPriority:(priority ? 0.55 : 0.35)];
```

where priority is boolean type variable. The link to the .m file on GitHub is: https://github.com/SopJS/cordova-plugin-pdf-viewer/blob/master/src/ios/ReaderThumbCache.m. This class caches thumbnail images to be shown for different PDF pages. In terms of qualityOfService, what should the above statement transform to? I am trying something like this right now:

```
thumbFetch.qualityOfService = (priority ? NSOperationQualityOfServiceUserInteractive:
                                                      NSOperationQualityOfServiceBackground);
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Consider: [thumbFetch setQueuePriority:(priority ? NSOperationQueuePriorityNormal : NSOperationQueuePriorityLow)];